# Converting from Forms Authentication to Windows Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication

We're currently using forms authentication for our intranet site and would like to allow users to authenticate via windows authentication instead. How will this affect current user accounts, profiles and roles. I have seen on the web that I can mix the two authentication types and put roles and profiles in a separate DB, but how do I link up **existing** role and profile assignments with windows authentication user logins?

Comment: Active Directory? Works just fine with forms authentication, side-by-side.

Comment: Yes, AD, but the question isn't about whether they can exist side by side, but rather how to convert from one to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally coming back around to answer the question. We actually kind of scrapped what we had in our Forms Authentication. The Roles work pretty differently with Windows authentication, as does the profile. We used a custom profile provider rather than the built in profile provider. If anyone is interested in what we've done, I put together a series of four blog posts that detail what we did in our environment and some of the glitches we ran into: [Part 1](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/net_discoveries/archive/2012/06/14/The-Other-Side-of-ASP.Net-Windows-Authentication_2C00_-Part-1.aspx), [Part 2](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/net_discoveries/archive/2012/07/02/The-Other-Side-of-ASP.Net-Windows-Authentication_2C00_-Part-2.aspx), [Part 3](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/net_discoveries/archive/2012/08/01/The-Other-Side-of-ASP.Net-Windows-Authentication_2C00_-Part-3.aspx) and [Part 4](http://aspadvice.com/blogs/net_discoveries/archive/2012/08/15/The-Other-Side-of-ASP.Net-Windows-Authentication_2C00_-Part-4.aspx).

Comment: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/net_discoveries/archive/2012/06/14/The-Other-Side-of-ASP.Net-Windows-Authentication_2C00_-Part-1.aspx not found

Comment: http://aspadvice.com/blogs/net_discoveries/archive/2012/07/02/The-Other-Side-of-ASP.Net-Windows-Authentication_2C00_-Part-2.aspx part2 not found

Comment: Yes, aspadvice is off the air. I'll have to find a different place to post the articles.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if you can do it exactly what you are asking however you could code your way out of this, you could write functionality that requires people who are windows authenticated to enter a credential you already have on file which is unique (say an email address) you could then convert the user account programatically if they responded by clicking a link.

You could create the new account and import the information from the old non windows authenticated account and then delete the old account. All db records that relyon UserId however would need to be changed in this approach as part of migration.

Comment: So kind of have an 'upgrade' wizard? Have them enter some kind of credentials to their forms authentication information, reinsert it with the new ID credentials and then delete the old Form's information for that user?

Comment: Yes @yougotiger thats what i mean. I'd be interested to see what others say however

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how integrated you want to be but if it's single sign on that't driving this.
get the user's sid look for it in profiles roles etc (could add sid column to them but a simple sid - userid table would be better.

if they are in there you are good to go.
if they aren't use the forms athentication to identify them and add a mapping from their sid touserid. So they'll get asked once more and thats it.

You'll probably need a similar mechanism anyway, in the event of the sid changing, which can happen after various windows issues. or for say anonymous access for non windows users.

if you don't like sid as an id then some other e.g domain\user name might do it.

windows groups/roles to application roles for full integration is another step, as would
rationalising profile info like full name etc..

it's nice quick start any way without having to trawl through everything that uses user id now and change it.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, you're recommending to create a new table that will hold the AD SID and the Form Authentication's UserID so that they two exist side by side and it translates back and forth? I.e. when I want to get their profile, I'd look up their SID by checking their login and then pulling the profile for the corresponding UserID?

Comment: Other way round, you get the sid from the authenticated login, then look up their existing profile. If it's there use it and all your current stuff will just work, if it's not authenticate with forms, and then add teh sid map for next time.